# Using C#, how to retrieve list of emails from Gmail server via POP3

Tags: c#, asp.net, gmail, pop3

Hy,

I have an application that sends mails with Gmail SMTP server (smtp.gmail.com) using SSL.

Now I want to read the emails from that account, does anyone have any idea how can I make this programatically in C# and ASP.NET?

At this point I'm using this code:

```
TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
tcpClient.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 587);

NetworkStream netStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
System.IO.StreamReader strReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(netStream);

Label7.Text = strReader.ReadLine() + "<br />"; 
//Label7.Text = "Server connected!";

byte[] WriteBuffer = new byte[1024];
ASCIIEncoding enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();

WriteBuffer = enc.GetBytes("USER " + TextBox4.Text + "\r\n");
netStream.Write(WriteBuffer, 0, WriteBuffer.Length);
Label7.Text += strReader.ReadLine() + "<br />";

WriteBuffer = enc.GetBytes("PASS " + TextBox5.Text + "\r\n");
netStream.Write(WriteBuffer, 0, WriteBuffer.Length);
Label7.Text += strReader.ReadLine() + "<br />";

WriteBuffer = enc.GetBytes("LIST\r\n");
netStream.Write(WriteBuffer, 0, WriteBuffer.Length);

String ListMessage;
while (true)
{
    ListMessage = strReader.ReadLine();
    if (ListMessage == ".")
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        Label7.Text += ListMessage + "<br />";
        continue;
    }
}

WriteBuffer = enc.GetBytes("QUIT\r\n");
netStream.Write(WriteBuffer, 0, WriteBuffer.Length);
Label7.Text += strReader.ReadLine() + "<br />";
```

And when I debug it it's shows that it's connected but no response in retrieving emails.

Comment: Shouldn't be pop.gmail.com instead of smtp.gmail.com in the TcpClient.Connect address?

Comment: Ahh yes, my mistake, I have edited to pop.gmail.com but I still have the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POP3 features of this [open source project](http://mailsystem.codeplex.com) (I'm involved in) contains everything you need. Including secure communications support & advanced authentication.

If you really want to do one yourself, browsing the source code will probably save you days of development.

Comment: and this is working with any kind of account? Like a gmail account?

Comment: Any POP3 account, including gmail.

Comment: This project is dead on codeplex.. The samples don't even build.

Comment: @Seany84: you must reference the DLL you previously compiled, or use the latest release

Answer (score 0):

I´m using this sample library that appeared at The Code Project [link text](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/despop3client.aspx)
that has a nice and clean api to work with pop3.